# EV3 software with large blocks

Tags: ev3, mindstorms

I can't seem to find a download for home or education version of EV3 software that has the large white blocks for either macos 10.13 or 10.15 on my imac.
Can someone help?

I currently have that version on ipad but imac version Home 1.3.0 is slender blocks and not as cool.  This is for the ev3 education kit.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.lego.com/en-us/themes/mindstorms/downloads

Scroll a bit down and you'll find two apple icons.

[image]

The left one will work for macOS 10.15 (Catalina) or newer, and is with what you describe slender blocks. It's similar to the Scratch educational programming environment.
The software is "pre-release" so might still have some kinks in it.

The right one is the older software with the blocks you are used to.
HOWEVER it will NOT work on macOS 10.15 or later.

Rather than porting their existing application to 10.15, LEGO has decided to spend their resources on the new app. Unfortunate decision in my opinion.

Comment: The Education version is available at https://education.lego.com/en-us/downloads/retiredproducts/mindstorms-ev3-lab/software

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Home edition of the retired software for MacOS 10.13 here: [Home edition](https://apps.apple.com/app/lego-mindstorms-ev3-home/id1479815442) (It will also work with education edition)